# Set ORC file name

Tags: hadoop, hive, etl

I'm currently implementing ETL (Talend) of monitoring data to HDFS, and Hive table.
I am now facing concerns about duplicates. More in details, if we need to run one ETL Job 2 times with the same input, we will end up with duplicates in our Hive table.

The solution to that in RDMS would have been to store the input file name and to "DELETE WHERE file name=..." before sending the data. But Hive is not a RDBMS, and does not support deletes.

I would like to have your advice on how to handle this. I envisage two solutions :

- Actually, the ETL is putting CSV files to the HDFS, which are used to feed an ORC table with a "INSERT INTO TABLE ... SELECT ..." The problem is that, with this operation, I'm losing the file name, and the ORC file is named 00000. **Is it possible to specify the file name of this created ORC file ?** If yes, I would be able to search the data by it's file name and delete it before launching the ETL.
- I'm not used to Hive's ACID capability (feature on Hive 0.14+). **Would you recommend to enable ACID with Hive ?** Will I be able to "DELETE WHERE" with it ?

Feel free to propose should you have any other solution to that.

Bests,
Orlando

Comment: What about loading all the files into a temp table and load final table using INSERT OVERWRITE ... SELECT DISTINCT..

Comment: By doing this, I will indeed avoid duplicates in each run of the ETL, but I won't be able to avoid duplicates coming for 2 runs withs the same input. Moreover, a INSERT OVERWRITE would lead to data loss if multiple input files are stored in the same partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering myself. I found a solution :
I partitionned my table with (date,**input_file_name**) (note, I can get the input_file_name with SELECT INPUT__FILE__NAME in Hive.
Once I did this, before running the ETL, I can send to Hive an ALTER TABLE DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (file_name=...) so that the folder containing the input data is deleted if this INPUT_FILE has already been sent to the ORC table.

Thank you everyone for your help.

Cheers,
Orlando

Answer (score 0):

If the data volume in target table is **not too large**, I would advise

```
INSERT INTO TABLE trg
SELECT ... FROM src
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT 1
  FROM trg x
  WHERE x.key =src.key
    AND <<additional filter on target to reduce data volume>> 
 )
```

Hive will automatically rewrite the correlated sub-query into a MapJoin, extracting all candidate keys in target table into a Java HashMap, and filtering source rows on-the-fly. As long as the HashMap can fit in the RAM available for Mappers heap size *(check your default conf files, increase with a `set` command in Hive script if necessary)* the performance will be sub-optimal, but you can be pretty sure that you will not have any duplicate.

And **in your actual use case** you don't have to check *each key* but only a "batch ID", more precisely the original file name; the way I've done it in my previous job was

```
INSERT INTO TABLE trg
SELECT ..., INPUT__FILE__NAME as original_file_name
FROM src
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT DISTINCT 1
  FROM trg x
  WHERE x.INPUT__FILE__NAME =src.original_file_name
    AND <<additional filter on target to reduce data volume>> 
 )
```

That implies an extra column in your target table, but since ORC is a columnar format, it's the number of distinct values that matter -- so that the overhead would stay low.

Note the explicit "DISTINCT" in the sub-query; a mature DBMS optimizer would automatically do it at execution time, but Hive does not (not yet) so you have to force it. Note also the "1" is just a dummy value required because of "SELECT" semantics; again, a mature DBMS would allow a dummy "null" but some versions of Hive would crash (e.g. with Tez in V0.14) so "1" or "'A'" are safer.

Reference:

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries#LanguageManualSubQueries-SubqueriesintheWHEREClause
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VirtualColumns

Comment: Hi Samson, thank you for this very clear answer. I indeed thought as a solution like this. My table is not very large (~500Go a year). But I still have doubt about performances of this solution : Will it imply to store all the data in this table twice temporarily ?

Comment: Nothing to *store* except the filename thing. It's a matter of *scanning* the table each time, to get a list of keys. And the nice thing with ORC is that the I/O will be limited to stripe footers *(checking whether the <<additional filter on another column>> is met -- e.g. "insert date not older than 1 month" vs. min/max values of insert date in that stripe)* then to the content of the matching stripes, focusing on the key column only. That's not a FULL scan.

Comment: OK thank you for the clarification. And what about the ACID capability of Hive ? Since I'll be storing the file name in the table, will a DELETE WHERE file name = .. result in a FULL SCAN ?

Comment: Since HDFS uses *immutable* files (OK, now there are exceptions, but they don't matter for Hive) a DELETE would mean create-a-copy-of-the-original-files-without-these-records-and-replace-the-original-files. Either immediately, or later (transaction mode requires a background process for garbage collection at HDFS level). I never heard any enthousiastic report about that. It's just a band-aid, and mostly aimed at people who need micro-batch INSERTs (e.g. with Flume) where periodic background compaction makes senses.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback on this. It's really helpfull. I'll go for your solution or change my table partitions to allow droping a whole partition. Thanks again.